# How to show multiple images in UICollectionView Swift

Tags: ios, swift

This extension gives only one UIImageView inside CollectionView. How to show more images, depends of the size of photos array. Photos array contains array of Url to images (String).

```
extension FlatViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource{
        func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return (flat.photos?.count)!
        }
        func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell

            cell.imageView.loadImageFromURL(NSURL(string: flat.image!)!)
            return cell
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can simply go into Interface Builder and put in the amount of `ImageView elements` into your `CollectionViewCell` as you would want. Then create `IBOutlets` to reference your added `ImageView` elements in your `CollectionViewController`. Then within the function `cellForItemAtIndexPath` just plug in each the Image URL for each `IBOutlet ImageView's`.

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

In `UICollectionViewCell` subclass programmatically create `UIImageView`s based on the photos array's subarrays. You can do this by setting up two protocols and implementing a delegate pattern where your `FlatViewController` is the delegate of your subclass.

The protocols would look something like this:

```
protocol PhotoDelegate {

  var photos: [[NSURL]] { get set }

}

protocol HasPhotos {

  var delegate: PhotoDelegate! { get set }

}
```

The delegate pattern will allow you to access the `photos` array from the subclass. You should set the dequeued cell variable's delegate property and cast it as your subclass in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Like So

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "<Insert Identifier>", for: indexPath) as! Subclass
cell.delegate = self
```

If you have any questions just ask! I love to help.